# Android Button View Binding ClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-button, android-viewbinding

The clickListener on my button is not working, I'm wondering if there is a known issue or I'm missing something?:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mMainBinding = MainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(R.layout.main)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.login_button)
    mMainBinding.loginButton.setOnClickListener {
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried moving the mMainBinding initialization below setContentView, tried it with a MaterialButton and a normal Button. Using "button" initialized with findViewById it works, but using the binding it doesn't. If I ctrl + click on loginButton it navigates to the right button in the xml layout, the button is also clickable, so what am I missing?

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.main)` – That's creating an instance of the layout that is completely separate from the binding setup. You need to call `setContentView()` with `mMainBinding.root` instead.

Comment: @MikeM. that was it! thx! I had before mMainBinding.root, but Android Studio doesn't list the layout file beside the class declaration when setting it through bindnig so I changed it. Strangely, not that I set the layout with binding.root I had a new problem, the margins of the layout get ignored, so I think that would be for a new question.

Comment: No problem. Do you mean margins on the root View? Using one of the [`DataBindingUtils.setContentView() methods`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil#setcontentview) instead might fix that. At least, it looks like they properly inflate the layout with its parent, from a quick glance at the source.

Comment: Yes, the margins of the root view get ignored. I'm not using DataBinding, only ViewBinding for now.

Comment: Oh, right, you did specify `View` binding. My bad.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe let `setContentView()` do its thing, then do the binding. That is: `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, `mMainBinding = MainBinding.bind(findViewById<View>(R.id.root_view_in_your_layout))`.

Comment: First one didn't work, second did, but in reality it's only a workaround, it seems like a bug in the binding lib to me, maybe I will stick with traditional methods for now.

Comment: You still have to call `setContentView()` with the first one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2pTI.png. Sorry, I omitted it just for brevity. Anyhoo, doing the `bind()` afterward, at least, isn't really a workaround. They intentionally offered various methods to effect the binding for just these kinds of situations.

Comment: Do skip that first one, though, now that I think about it. I'm pretty sure it's possible for the `Window` to not have created the decor by that time, so it would fail in that case, which might be what you were seeing in your particular setup.

Comment: I realized this morning that we actually can use that first suggestion if we force the decor creation first: `MainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, window.decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content), false)`. And it turns out that this is pretty much exactly what `DataBindingUtil` is doing. These aren't workarounds; rather, they're steps necessary to insert this external binding stuff into the existing framework. I suppose the lack of a similar `View` binding util could be considered a (minor) bug, but whether we do it or the library does it, it's all using the same framework mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Activity then you can try to use ->

**binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);**

and if you are using Fragment then try - >

**binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_your_videos, container, false);
view = binding.getRoot();
return view;**

It may be issue in [DataBinding](https://fluttertpoint.com/android-databinding)